Bootstrap Accordion in wordpress functions.php
I am making a shortcode in wordpress, including bootstrap accordion so that when I put the shortcode in the editor it gives me the posts title, image, categories, content etc.
When I am putting bootstrap html in the post editor and make different shortcode for each posts entities, it’s working fine. But when I put the bootstrap html code inside the function.php and make one shortcode, everything is working only accordion collapse is not working. [i guess related to bootstrap javascript not working when html elements with classes are in the functions.php]

function hello_elementor_child_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'hello-elementor-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        [
            'hello-elementor-theme-style',
        ],
        HELLO_ELEMENTOR_CHILD_VERSION
    );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-cdn-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-cdn-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hello_elementor_child_scripts_styles', 20 );


Here is my code [i already added bootstrap JS and CSS in functions.php]

function program_post_list_acc($atts){
    $post = get_the_post_thumbnail($atts['id'], 'medium');
    $image = apply_filters( 'thumbnail', $post);
    $fullcon .='<div class="panel-group" id="accordion"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#acc'. $atts['id'].'"><span class="program-class-thumb"><div style="display:inline-block;" >'. $image .'</div><div class="program-class-lines" style="display:inline-block;">';

    $post_program = get_post($atts['id']);
        $tit = apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_program->post_title );
        $fullcon .='<div class="program-class-firstline">'. $tit . '</div>';
    $post_categories1 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'teachers');
    $post_categories2 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_durations');
    $post_categories3 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_levels');
    $post_categories4 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_purpose');
    $post_categories5 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_style');
    $categories1 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories1, 'name' );
    $categories2 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories2, 'name' );
    $categories3 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories3, 'name' );
    $categories4 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories4, 'name' );
    $categories5 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories5, 'name' );
    $categories = array_merge($categories2, $categories3, $categories4, $categories5);
    $fullcon .='<div class="program-class-secondline">';
    foreach ( $categories1 as $cat):
        $fullcon .='<span class="program-class-tag1">'. $cat . '</span>';
        endforeach;
    $fullcon .='</div>';    
    $fullcon .='<div class="program-class-thirdline">';
    foreach( $categories as $category):
        $fullcon .='<span class="program-class-tag2">'. $category . '</span>';
        endforeach;
    $fullcon .='</div></div></span></a></h4></div>';
        $output = Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content($atts['id']);
    $fullcon .='<div id="acc'. $atts['id'].'" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body">'. $output .'</div></div></div></div>';    
    return $fullcon;
} 
add_shortcode('program_post_list_accordian', 'program_post_list_acc');

All values are returning fine. Only accordion is not expending/collapsing
Here I am sharing some screen shot:
This screenshot- when i am adding html to post editor with using 4 shortcodes: more complicated
Adding html from post editor, I have to make 4 shortcodes, but accordion is working very well, with all post datas
but when I make only one shortcode and add all html to functions.php, this is the output, post data is there, even post content I can see from source code of web, but accordion now not working ie. not expending/collapsing
I hope these screenshots will be helpful to solve the problem.
Seems I found the solution
I just try something suggested in other questions and change my code by using ob_start(); and its working now.....
Here is my new code-------------
function program_post_list_acc($atts){
    ob_start();
    $post = get_the_post_thumbnail($atts['id'], 'medium');
    $image = apply_filters( 'thumbnail', $post);
    ?>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#acc<?php echo $atts['id'];?>">
    <span class="program-class-thumb"><div style="display:inline-block;" ><?php echo $image; ?></div>
    <div class="program-class-lines" style="display:inline-block;">
<?php
    $post_program = get_post($atts['id']);
        $tit = apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_program->post_title ); ?>
        <div class="program-class-firstline"><?php echo $tit; ?></div>
<?php        
    $post_categories1 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'teachers');
    $post_categories2 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_durations');
    $post_categories3 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_levels');
    $post_categories4 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_purpose');
    $post_categories5 = get_the_terms( $atts['id'], 'classes_style');
    $categories1 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories1, 'name' );
    $categories2 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories2, 'name' );
    $categories3 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories3, 'name' );
    $categories4 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories4, 'name' );
    $categories5 = wp_list_pluck( $post_categories5, 'name' );
    $categories = array_merge($categories2, $categories3, $categories4, $categories5); ?>
    <div class="program-class-secondline"> 
<?php    
    foreach ( $categories1 as $cat): ?>
        <span class="program-class-tag1"><?php echo $cat; ?></span> 
<?php        
        endforeach; ?>
    </div>    
    <div class="program-class-thirdline">
<?php    
    foreach( $categories as $category): ?>
        <span class="program-class-tag2"><?php echo $category; ?></span>
<?php        
        endforeach; ?>
    </div></div></span></a></h4></div>
<?php    
    $output = Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content($atts['id']); ?>
    <div id="acc<?php echo $atts['id']; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"><?php echo $output; ?></div></div></div></div>
<?php    
    return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode('program_post_list_accordian', 'program_post_list_acc');

Thanks to the community

Welcome! Please show us your rendered HTML. It's really hard to debug PHP code when we can't see what the actual output is.

Thanks for participating to help me out @disinfor , I have added some screenshots above with my problem.
